# Is it possible in android to define constants in XML that vary with configuration

Tags: android, xml, layout, constants

I am interested in having an XML layouts in Android change size depending on landscape or portrait viewing (and maybe other configurations later).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="@drawable/stream_bg_1px_wide"
android:layout_height="150dip" >
```

In this example I *just* want to vary the 150dip size depending on landscape or portrait, not change anything else.

I am using layout and layout-land, and I know I could repeat the layout in each of those folders, but that makes maintaining changes in it a bit of a pain. When I introduce more variants based on screen density and size it just gets worse.

So, I wondered if it's possible to define a value (constant) in an XML file, and reference it from my layout, similar to how colors can be defined

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="shopper_background"> #FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

along the lines of......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <value name="footer_size" >150</value>
</resources>
```

Then I could just replicate that file, with different values, in each config.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. A dimension is an accepted item in a resource file. So create e.g. res/values/dimension.xml and put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="footer_size" >150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 40):

Yes you can do this, we do it all over the place in Android itself :) Just define your constants in res/values/, res/values-land/ etc. For dimensions, use the  tag and refer to them using @dimen/my_value in the layout.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain it shortly.

First, you may notice that now you should use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.html) as requested by google (see androix library).

In your android studio projet, you can provide screen-specific layouts by creating additional res/layout/ directories. One for each screen configuration that requires a different layout.

This means you have to use the **directory qualifier** in both cases :

- Android device support
- Android landscape or portrait mode

As a result, here is an exemple :

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml                # For handsets
res/layout-land/main_activity.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml        # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets in landscape
```

You can also use qualifier with res ressources files using dimens.xml.

```
res/values/dimens.xml                # For handsets
res/values-land/dimens.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml        # For 7” tablets
```

res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="grid_view_item_height">70dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

res/values-land/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="grid_view_item_height">150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

your_item_grid_or_list_layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_view_item_height"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Source : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes