# equal TextView height in different screen resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

On layout I have listview

```
<com...DynamicListView 
        android:id="@+id/listview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
        android:layout_weight="0.34" 
        android:background="#0000" 
        android:divider="@null" 
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />
```

to which was added 4-th TextView.
**text_view.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_size" />
```

How can I make them all the same height and climbed onto the screen on screens with different resolutions (without the appearance of the scroll)?

**Update**

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
    }
}

...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  ...
  int myDPValue = 60;
  myDPValue = (int) ((int) myDPValue * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, myDPValue);
  view.setLayoutParams(params);

  return view;
}
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Who are **THEM**?

Comment: items in listview(textview)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please ask what you want clearly (possibly adding a picture - even a link to it); show what you tried; if getting errors, show the logcat

Comment: I add textview in listview. If I set android:layout_height="60dp" in text_view.xml how as in example, in my device is all ok, but on other this items is big and they can not fit in listview and is presented scroll

Comment: I use your scale algorithm in my adapter(I updated my post). Maybe, I didn't understand you, but everything remains as it was

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking to adjust the height based on the size of the screen of the various devices. For this, you can take advantage of the `res/values/dimens.xml` file, along with how Android does resource configurations. You can redefine the same `dimen` for each screen density or size that you'd like. See the following links for your answers:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension
- [Is it possible in android to define constants in XML that vary with configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285429/is-it-possible-in-android-to-define-constants-in-xml-that-vary-with-configuratio)
- http://programthat.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/how-to-set-up-a-dimensions-xml-file/

Comment: I did not understand how dimens help me, if the first device is normal size 60dp, on the second 40dp, on the third 30dp.

Comment: Android allows many different resource configurations in the 'res/' directory. (See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) So you can have a 'res/values-sw320dp/dimens.xml' and a 'res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml' for example. Therefore, if you know the screen densities of the devices you are targeting, then you can define different values for your dimensions for those screens.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have scrolling, then you should not use a `ListView`. You should use a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation instead, and use equal weights for the items if you want to have them resized to fit the available space on the screen.

Comment: no, listview this is what I need. I use listview because I found nice drag and drop for it.

Comment: @boroloro: What do you mean by drag and drop?

Comment: @boroloro: This seems to be a generic framework, so you should be able to implement it with a `LinearLayout` as well if you wish.

Comment: I said that already found a great example that suits me http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q